# How to force PyCharm to show the contents of all print() statements in the Run Window

Tags: python, pycharm

I have included a number of other functions in my main function which have made the output of the Run window, to be truncated. 
Is there a way to force pyCharm to show all output from print statements?

[image]

I can write the output to a file via Run > Edit Configurations > log tab but the preference is the Run window, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this setting:

`File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Console: Use soft wraps in console`